# What's the purpose of persisting entities?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have read the documentation many times at http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html but I still don't get it.

What's the purpose of persiting entities?

I have the following code

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$user = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
if ($user) {
    $user->enabled(1);
    $em->flush();
}
```

It works very well.

Why should I add the

```
$em->persist($user);
```

before the flush ?

Comment: my rep would appreciate it if you could accept my answer, if it truly answers your question.

Comment: any chance you could accept the answer here?

Answer (score 3):

`persisting` an entity just means that the entity manager can *manage* the entity. otherwise it doesn't know about it.

EDIT: if you are working with an entity that has been pulled from the entity manager to begin with (in your case, `$user`), then persisting is not required because the entity manager already "knows" about it. So persisting is only required when creating a NEW instance.

> An entity can be made persistent by passing it to the EntityManager#persist($entity) method. By applying the persist operation on some entity, that entity becomes MANAGED, which means that its persistence is from now on managed by an EntityManager. As a result the persistent state of such an entity will subsequently be properly synchronized with the database when EntityManager#flush() is invoked.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#persisting-entities